# Running two web applications on Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, centos7, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run two applications on my Linux apache server:

- OpenProject
- pgAdmin (which is WSGI application)

And, in order to connect them from remote computer, I use those `httpd` configuration files:

For OpenProject:

```
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 198.162.12.13
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public

  ProxyRequests off

  Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/vhost/*.conf

  # Can't use Location block since it would overshadow all the other proxypass directives on CentOS
  ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>
```

For pgAdmin:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName 198.162.214.23
    WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin4 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25

    <Directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/>
        WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And now magic (for me) begins and where my question lies:

take a look at server names in both files, pgAdmin contains my actual IP address, while OpenProject has some random IP address.

With that setup, pgAdmin works, but OpenProject doesn't.

Generally, without configuration for pgAdmin, OpenProject works with any IP address, which is strange for me, so my first question is: why???

**So, to sum up:**

If I set up in both files my actual IP address, then OpenProject works, pgAdmin doesn't.

If I set up in both files some random IP address, then OpenProject works, pgAdmin doesn't.

If I set up actual IP for OpenProject, random for pgAdmin, then OpenProject works, pgAdmin doesn't.

If I set up random IP for OpenProject, actual IP for pgAdmin, then OpenProject doesn't work, but pgAdmin does.

Why it is so messed up? How to configure those files so both applications work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DNS  to create two names (e.g., `openproject.example` and `pgadmin.example`) pointing to the actual address (apparently 198.162.12.13) of your server. Configure these names in the respective `ServerName` settings, and use http://openproject.example and http://pgadmin.example to access them.

Comment: Will it be visible from other comouter?

Comment: Also, my acutal IP is 192.168.214.23. OpenProject runs on whatever IP address (specified in `ServerName`), which seems also strange to me.

Comment: And how to "use DNS"? Do you mean to specify `ServerName` to those names?

Answer (score 2):

To run multiple separate web sites / applications on a single IP-address you have roughly three options:

- You install each application  in a different URL paths i.e. `$(hostname)/app1` and `/app2`.

If both applications need to be installed in the root `/` your options are to

- run multiple virtual web servers  on different port numbers and `http://$(hostname):81/` will show one application and `http://$(hostname):82/` can show a different one
- run multiple virtual web servers under different host names and do [name based virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html). Then `http://app1.example.com/` can show one application and `http://app2.example.com/` will show another

Your config appears an attempt to use that last option but since both VirtualHost definitions get configured with the same `ServerName` Apache cannot distinguish them.

Comment: Note that the ServerNames *are* different, though in an unexpected way ...